# running puppet psych errors

Tags: ruby, puppet, psych

I'm trying to run a puppet apply and thrown with bunch of errors.

hiera -c /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml classes

generates the following :

```
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 238 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend/yaml_backend.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/filecache.rb:53:in `read_file'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend/yaml_backend.rb:17:in `block in lookup'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:104:in `block in datasourcefiles'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:76:in `block in datasources'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:74:in `map'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:74:in `datasources'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:99:in `datasourcefiles'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend/yaml_backend.rb:16:in `lookup'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:206:in `block in lookup'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:203:in `each'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:203:in `lookup'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera.rb:60:in `lookup'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/hiera-1.3.4/bin/hiera:225:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/hiera:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/hiera:23:in `<main>'
```

contents of the file:

```
require 'psych.so'
require 'psych/nodes'
require 'psych/streaming'
require 'psych/visitors'
require 'psych/handler'
require 'psych/tree_builder'
require 'psych/parser'
require 'psych/omap'
require 'psych/set'
require 'psych/coder'
require 'psych/core_ext'
require 'psych/deprecated'
require 'psych/stream'
require 'psych/json/tree_builder'
require 'psych/json/stream'
require 'psych/handlers/document_stream'

###
# = Overview
#
# Psych is a YAML parser and emitter.
# Psych leverages libyaml [Home page: http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML]
# or [Git repo: https://github.com/zerotao/libyaml] for its YAML parsing
# and emitting capabilities. In addition to wrapping libyaml, Psych also
# knows how to serialize and de-serialize most Ruby objects to and from
# the YAML format.
#
# = I NEED TO PARSE OR EMIT YAML RIGHT NOW!
#
#   # Parse some YAML
#   Psych.load("--- foo") # => "foo"
#
#   # Emit some YAML
#   Psych.dump("foo")     # => "--- foo\n...\n"
#   { :a => 'b'}.to_yaml  # => "---\n:a: b\n"
#
# Got more time on your hands?  Keep on reading!
#
# == YAML Parsing
#
# Psych provides a range of interfaces for parsing a YAML document ranging from
# low level to high level, depending on your parsing needs.  At the lowest
# level, is an event based parser.  Mid level is access to the raw YAML AST,
# and at the highest level is the ability to unmarshal YAML to ruby objects.
#
# === Low level parsing
#
# The lowest level parser should be used when the YAML input is already known,
# and the developer does not want to pay the price of building an AST or
# automatic detection and conversion to ruby objects.  See Psych::Parser for
# more information on using the event based parser.
#
# === Mid level parsing
#
# Psych provides access to an AST produced from parsing a YAML document.  This
# tree is built using the Psych::Parser and Psych::TreeBuilder.  The AST can
# be examined and manipulated freely.  Please see Psych::parse_stream,
# Psych::Nodes, and Psych::Nodes::Node for more information on dealing with
# YAML syntax trees.
#
# === High level parsing
#
# The high level YAML parser provided by Psych simply takes YAML as input and
# returns a Ruby data structure.  For information on using the high level parser
# see Psych.load
#
# == YAML Emitting
#
# Psych provides a range of interfaces ranging from low to high level for
# producing YAML documents.  Very similar to the YAML parsing interfaces, Psych
# provides at the lowest level, an event based system, mid-level is building
# a YAML AST, and the highest level is converting a Ruby object straight to
# a YAML document.
#
# === Low level emitting
#
# The lowest level emitter is an event based system.  Events are sent to a
# Psych::Emitter object.  That object knows how to convert the events to a YAML
# document.  This interface should be used when document format is known in
# advance or speed is a concern.  See Psych::Emitter for more information.
#
# === Mid level emitting
#
# At the mid level is building an AST.  This AST is exactly the same as the AST
# used when parsing a YAML document.  Users can build an AST by hand and the
# AST knows how to emit itself as a YAML document.  See Psych::Nodes,
# Psych::Nodes::Node, and Psych::TreeBuilder for more information on building
# a YAML AST.
#
# === High level emitting
#
# The high level emitter has the easiest interface.  Psych simply takes a Ruby
# data structure and converts it to a YAML document.  See Psych.dump for more
# information on dumping a Ruby data structure.

module Psych
  # The version is Psych you're using
  VERSION         = '2.0.0'

  # The version of libyaml Psych is using
  LIBYAML_VERSION = Psych.libyaml_version.join '.'

  class Exception < RuntimeError
  end

  class BadAlias < Exception
  end

  ###
  # Load +yaml+ in to a Ruby data structure.  If multiple documents are
  # provided, the object contained in the first document will be returned.
  # +filename+ will be used in the exception message if any exception is raised
  # while parsing.
  #
  # Raises a Psych::SyntaxError when a YAML syntax error is detected.
  #
  # Example:
  #
  #   Psych.load("--- a")             # => 'a'
  #   Psych.load("---\n - a\n - b")   # => ['a', 'b']
  #
  #   begin
  #     Psych.load("--- `", "file.txt")
  #   rescue Psych::SyntaxError => ex
  #     ex.file    # => 'file.txt'
  #     ex.message # => "(file.txt): found character that cannot start any token"
  #   end
  def self.load yaml, filename = nil
    result = parse(yaml, filename)
    result ? result.to_ruby : result
  end

  ###
  # Parse a YAML string in +yaml+.  Returns the first object of a YAML AST.
  # +filename+ is used in the exception message if a Psych::SyntaxError is
  # raised.
  #
  # Raises a Psych::SyntaxError when a YAML syntax error is detected.
  #
  # Example:
  #
  #   Psych.parse("---\n - a\n - b") # => #<Psych::Nodes::Sequence:0x00>
  #
  #   begin
  #     Psych.parse("--- `", "file.txt")
  #   rescue Psych::SyntaxError => ex
  #     ex.file    # => 'file.txt'
  #     ex.message # => "(file.txt): found character that cannot start any token"
  #   end
  #
  # See Psych::Nodes for more information about YAML AST.
  def self.parse yaml, filename = nil
    parse_stream(yaml, filename) do |node|
      return node
    end
    false
  end

  ###
  # Parse a file at +filename+. Returns the YAML AST.
  #
  # Raises a Psych::SyntaxError when a YAML syntax error is detected.
  def self.parse_file filename
    File.open filename, 'r:bom|utf-8' do |f|
      parse f, filename
    end
  end

  ###
  # Returns a default parser
  def self.parser
    Psych::Parser.new(TreeBuilder.new)
  end

  ###
  # Parse a YAML string in +yaml+.  Returns the full AST for the YAML document.
  # This method can handle multiple YAML documents contained in +yaml+.
  # +filename+ is used in the exception message if a Psych::SyntaxError is
  # raised.
  #
  # If a block is given, a Psych::Nodes::Document node will be yielded to the
  # block as it's being parsed.
  #
  # Raises a Psych::SyntaxError when a YAML syntax error is detected.
  #
  # Example:
  #
  #   Psych.parse_stream("---\n - a\n - b") # => #<Psych::Nodes::Stream:0x00>
  #
  #   Psych.parse_stream("--- a\n--- b") do |node|
  #     node # => #<Psych::Nodes::Document:0x00>
  #   end
  #
  #   begin
  #     Psych.parse_stream("--- `", "file.txt")
  #   rescue Psych::SyntaxError => ex
  #     ex.file    # => 'file.txt'
  #     ex.message # => "(file.txt): found character that cannot start any token"
  #   end
  #
  # See Psych::Nodes for more information about YAML AST.
  def self.parse_stream yaml, filename = nil, &block
    if block_given?
      parser = Psych::Parser.new(Handlers::DocumentStream.new(&block))
      parser.parse yaml, filename
    else
      parser = self.parser
      parser.parse yaml, filename
      parser.handler.root
    end
  end

  ###
  # call-seq:
  #   Psych.dump(o)               -> string of yaml
  #   Psych.dump(o, options)      -> string of yaml
  #   Psych.dump(o, io)           -> io object passed in
  #   Psych.dump(o, io, options)  -> io object passed in
  #
  # Dump Ruby object +o+ to a YAML string.  Optional +options+ may be passed in
  # to control the output format.  If an IO object is passed in, the YAML will
  # be dumped to that IO object.
  #
  # Example:
  #
  #   # Dump an array, get back a YAML string
  #   Psych.dump(['a', 'b'])  # => "---\n- a\n- b\n"
  #
  #   # Dump an array to an IO object
  #   Psych.dump(['a', 'b'], StringIO.new)  # => #<StringIO:0x000001009d0890>
  #
  #   # Dump an array with indentation set
  #   Psych.dump(['a', ['b']], :indentation => 3) # => "---\n- a\n-  - b\n"
  #
  #   # Dump an array to an IO with indentation set
  #   Psych.dump(['a', ['b']], StringIO.new, :indentation => 3)
  #def self.dump o, io = nil, options = {}
   def self.dump o, io = nil, options = {}
     if Hash === io
      options = io
      io      = nil
    end

    visitor = Psych::Visitors::YAMLTree.new options
    visitor << o
    visitor.tree.yaml io, options
  end

  ###
  # Dump a list of objects as separate documents to a document stream.
  #
  # Example:
  #
  #   Psych.dump_stream("foo\n  ", {}) # => "--- ! \"foo\\n  \"\n--- {}\n"
  def self.dump_stream *objects
    visitor = Psych::Visitors::YAMLTree.new {}
    objects.each do |o|
      visitor << o
    end
    visitor.tree.yaml
  end

  ###
  # Dump Ruby object +o+ to a JSON string.
  def self.to_json o
    visitor = Psych::Visitors::JSONTree.new
    visitor << o
    visitor.tree.yaml
  end

  ###
  # Load multiple documents given in +yaml+.  Returns the parsed documents
  # as a list.  If a block is given, each document will be converted to ruby
  # and passed to the block during parsing
  #
  # Example:
  #
  #   Psych.load_stream("--- foo\n...\n--- bar\n...") # => ['foo', 'bar']
  #
  #   list = []
  #   Psych.load_stream("--- foo\n...\n--- bar\n...") do |ruby|
  #     list << ruby
  #   end
  #   list # => ['foo', 'bar']
  #
  def self.load_stream yaml, filename = nil
    if block_given?
      parse_stream(yaml, filename) do |node|
        yield node.to_ruby
      end
    else
      parse_stream(yaml, filename).children.map { |child| child.to_ruby }
    end
  end

  ###
  # Load the document contained in +filename+.  Returns the yaml contained in
  # +filename+ as a ruby object
  def self.load_file filename
    File.open(filename, 'r:bom|utf-8') { |f| self.load f, filename }
  end

  # :stopdoc:
  @domain_types = {}
  def self.add_domain_type domain, type_tag, &block
    key = ['tag', domain, type_tag].join ':'
    @domain_types[key] = [key, block]
    @domain_types["tag:#{type_tag}"] = [key, block]
  end

  def self.add_builtin_type type_tag, &block
    domain = 'yaml.org,2002'
    key = ['tag', domain, type_tag].join ':'
    @domain_types[key] = [key, block]
  end

  def self.remove_type type_tag
    @domain_types.delete type_tag
  end

  @load_tags = {}
  @dump_tags = {}
  def self.add_tag tag, klass
    @load_tags[tag] = klass
    @dump_tags[klass] = tag
  end

  class << self
    attr_accessor :load_tags
    attr_accessor :dump_tags
    attr_accessor :domain_types
  end
  # :startdoc:
end
```

I have seen some references quoting

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

cannot find a config/boot.rb to try this.

I ripped out system wide ruby and the gems. Trying rvm and i still get similar errors :

I'm running hiera in debug mode :

```
[lame@TTBOX ~]$  hiera -d -c  eye
Cannot find config file: eye
[lame@ipTTBOX ~]$  hiera -d  eye
DEBUG: 2014-11-25 05:47:37 +0700: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2014-11-25 05:47:37 +0700: Looking up eye in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2014-11-25 05:47:37 +0700: Looking for data source default
/home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 238 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/psych-2.0.6/lib/psych.rb:245:in `load'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend/yaml_backend.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/filecache.rb:53:in `read_file'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend/yaml_backend.rb:17:in `block in lookup'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:104:in `block in datasourcefiles'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:76:in `block in datasources'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:74:in `map'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:74:in `datasources'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:99:in `datasourcefiles'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend/yaml_backend.rb:16:in `lookup'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:206:in `block in lookup'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:203:in `each'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera/backend.rb:203:in `lookup'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/lib/hiera.rb:60:in `lookup'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/hiera-1.3.4/bin/hiera:225:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/hiera:23:in `load'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/hiera:23:in `<main>'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /home/lame/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Are you suggesting me to have a look at the hiera file itself ?

Comment: The file content you've included is just the source file of the `psych` library. On line `205`, as mentioned in the error message, the library calls `parser.parse`. The error is coming from whatever file you're trying to parse, the contents of which are not included here in your question.

Comment: Did you try with 
  require 'yaml'
  YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psyck'

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says to look at line 238, column 3 of your yaml file. Check to see if you have any illegal characters there.

Comment: my assumption it is the following file: 

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Nov 24 03:24 /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/psych.rb -> /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/psych-2.0.0/lib/psych.rb

Comment: That's the library file, which is running the `parse` method that is throwing the error. The actual syntax error is in the file that `parse` is parsing.

Comment: Exactly - ignore the stack trace.